# Jquery - Insert new element, and animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, element

For example. Insert element to html, load image, (After load page!) CONTENT

```
 $('.inner').append('<div class="class_name">blabla</div>');
 $('.class_name').animate('left += 30', 3000); // animate
 $('.class_name').remove();
```

How Can i resolve this problem.

Function live doesn't help me. (Hmm bad usage?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you current problem, but your code has some issues:

See this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/UvLKx/)

**JQUERY**

```
// append
$('.inner').append('<div class="class_name">blabla</div>');

// animate the left
$('.class_name').animate({'left' : '+=30px'}, 3000, function() {

  // done animating, remove
  $('.class_name').remove();
});
```